# Iterate Through Dictionary Keys and Input Values using Tag Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have an asp.net core input form which needs to iterate through a dictionary with Key type 'Product' and Value type 'int' (where int is supposed to be the quantity of the products). It looks like this right now:

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<Product, int> product in Model.ProductQuantityDictionary)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @product.Key.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            <input asp-for="@product.Value" class="form-control" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

this is successfully showing the name of the products and the input fields with the right default values (0) but when I submit it is not actually submitting the dictionary entry. I think this is because I am only inputting the value and not the Key or the total KeyValuePair into the dictionary, but I'm not sure how to do that. I need to do something like for each pair of existing Key and inputted Value, update the entry in the dictionary (the dictionary already has all the number of entries it needs, all I am doing here is updating the values)

thanks for any help

edit: here's the viewmodel. I need to fill out that dictionary and then pass its values back and make product instances based on the quantity chosen in each pair

```
    public class ProductKit_ViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StyleId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Product, int> ProductQuantityDictionary { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a default tag helper for dictionaries.  Using `input asp-for` like this wouldn't be able to evaluate the correct meta data for the field from the ModelExpression `@product.Value`.

You will also have a problem binding to a dictionary with a 'Product' key

You could create a custom tag helper and custom model binder but easier workaround using the default model binders would be to use a `Dictionary<string, int>` instead and change you view like so:

```
@foreach (var kvp in Model.ProductQuantityDictionary) {
    var name = Html.NameFor(m => m.dict) + "[" + kvp.Key + "]";
    <tr>
        <td>@kvp.Key</td>
        <td><input name="@name" value="@kvp.Value" class="form-control" /></td>
    </tr>
}
```